# Column display on react bootstrap, despite being declared as 2 columns displays as one only

Tags: reactjs, containers, react-bootstrap

I have this code, which is supposed to display 1 row with 2 columns:

```
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col>1 of 2</Col>     
    <Col>2 of 2</Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

But surprisingly upon execute this is the result.

```
1 of 2
2 of 2
```

Anything I need to set so this will display as two columns as expected?  I tried also the fluid option on the container same result.

Comment: Did you use bootstrap?

Comment: can you post your actual code (at least the full component code if possible)

Comment: Already discovered this, I need to include bootstrap.min.css.

Answer (score 0):

This is already resolved, I just need to include the statement below to use the CSS.

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';